# dealing with uppercases when highlighting search results

Tags: angular

I have a searchbar with dynamic content below, and I'm trying to highlight the results if they match the input of the user.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search_input"/>
<div *ngFor="let text of list">
  <div [innerHTML]="format(text)">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the TS :

```
search_input: string = "";
list = ["Text 1. Hello world", "Text 2. hello world", "Text 3. Hello World"];

format(text) {
  if(this.search_input.length < 2){
    return text;
  }else{
    return text.replace(new RegExp(this.search_input, 'g'), "<b>"+this.search_input+"</b>");
  }
}
```

This is working great, but it is case sensitive. When I type "Hello", there are only text1 and text3 which highlight. I would like to be able to highlight all the results when typing "hello", or "Hello", or "HELLO"...

Thank you in advance for any help

Here is a demo :
https://embed.plnkr.co/BadMpUcVQY396eC0mRUl/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when typing *HELLO*, this replaces `hello world` by `HELLO world`, I'd like to keep the original format

Comment: `.replace(new RegExp(this.search_input, 'g'), "<b>$&</b>")` use the parameter `$&`, you can find more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,[image] it is working for me

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'src/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
search_input: string = "";
    list = ["Text 1. Hello world", "Text 2. hello world", "Text 3. Hello World"];

    format(text) {
      if(this.search_input.length < 2){
        return text;
      }else{
        var re = new RegExp(this.search_input, 'gi')
        return text.replace(re, "<b>$&</b>");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a stackblitz link or another online editor instead of posting a photo of code :)